# Accessing PCIE Device from multiple threads C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, linux-device-driver

I am using an API that allows me to interface with the hardware.  The API is organized as a class object that allows read, write and other functions, and it handles the interrupts and device handles.  My goal is to access the device throw multiple threads for concurrent/simultaneously work.  However, I am worried about thread safety or even correct functionality.  If each thread creates the object and handles the functions would that work without any extra steps?  Would the interrupts and handles that belong to the class cause any issues with the other thread?  Would the device properly handle the two threads?

I don't think there will be any race conditions or thread safety issues since every thread will have it's own class object.

Comment: You should probably have one thread that deals with the hardware, and others that pass messages to it over a thread-safe message channel.

Comment: The requirement is multiple threads working with the device

Comment: I'm just suggesting an architecture that will be easier to debug and get working. Unless you're really good at juggling mutexes and avoiding deadlocks, having a single point of control helps considerably. A low-cost abstraction gets you to your goal quickly. The threads can even work asynchronously if necessary, something super easy with message passing and an event loop.

Comment: Consider: If your hardware has any state whatsoever, being able to coordinate that across multiple threads will be a nightmare, and holding open a lock on the hardware will jam up all threads trying to access it. Plus if that thread doesn't clean up properly, the whole thing gets jammed.

Comment: You bring up a good point about mutex and deadlocks.  Would mutexes be needed, even if each thread has it's own instances of the class.  The data should be isolated.  My only concern is when accessing the device, would problems arise.

Comment: All your questions can only be answered by someone who knows "the API", it should document whether it is thread-safe

Comment: My goal was to understand the general process not so much specific to the API.  Meaning, how to work with a device from multiple threads.

Comment: And that goal cannot be reached without knowing how you are interacting with the device. Is it through a custom driver? Or perhaps UIO drivers? Are you using mmapped memory for interacting with the device?

Comment: You need to understand what you are doing with a hardware. Are you simply do IO reads and writes or more than that? I believe for the latter you need to have a *transaction* based accesses, where each *transaction* is protected. That's probably what your class has no clue about, so it's your responsibility to serialize them.

Comment: Also, how do you know that OS kernel is not involved in the devices accesses? And more important if your device is hotplug capable or not. If the former, you are in a really big troubles (I'm 99.9% sure your code or that class is quite buggy with hotplug). (And note, that hotplug can be simulated without a physical detach of the device)

Comment: @0andriy thank you. This is type of info I needed.  The API is just reading/writing from/to FPGA. I thought if each thread had a unique device handle it would satisfy thread safety.  Should I be introducing a lock on each read/write?

Comment: It's an unaswerable question by nobody, but you. It depends on what you are doing, what kind of reads and writes. Check the programming manual for your FPGA and decide how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

In order to interact with a limited ressource, you need to have two things : atomic operations and a locking mecanism.
The locking mecanism is often handled via lock and mutex (a lock is here to ensure that only one operation is performed on the device at a time so there is no ressource conflict access). an atomic operation is an operation that can be performed regardless of which atomic operation was performed before. so the main idea is that only one thread is accessing the api at a time (using locks) and that they dont put your device in a state where other threads could corrupt the well functionning of the friver

Comment: Thanks.  I would need a locking mechanism even if each thread had it's own unique device handle.